# Combining a mousedown event with a keydown event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to combine a keydown event with a mousedown event. Basically, I have a chat dialog, and if the user writes in one of 2 divs (keydown event) or makes a selection from either (or both) of 2 dropdowns (mousedown), I need these to have the same exact function. Thanks in advance.

Code (to be combined):

```
$('#usermsg').add('#otherComments').keydown(function() { // When key pressed
```

and

```
$('#strategies').add('#whySwitch').mousedown(function() { // When mouse is clicked
  //function body
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function that serves both the div and call it like,

```
$('#usermsg').add('#otherComments').keydown(functionToCall);

$('#strategies').add('#whySwitch').mousedown(functionToCall);
```

/*do not forget to remove ()*/

then the function implementation:

```
function functionToCall() {
    //body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if is the right way, but i everytime do it:

```
var keyPressed = new Object(); 
keyPressed.mouse = 0; 
keyPressed.keyboard = 0;
```

one event to keydown and keyup, and another one to mouseup and mousedown

both events keydown and mousedown sets keyPressed.mouse or keyboard to 1 both events keyup and mouseup sets keyPressed.mouse or keyboard to 0

mousedown and and keydown will call a function who see if mouse and keyboard are down and do something you want.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the callback function and provide its name in both events as callback function argument.

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
$('#usermsg').add('#otherComments').keydown(yourFunction);
```

and

```
$('#strategies').add('#whySwitch').mousedown(yourFunction);
```

then

```
function yourFunction() {
// do what you want
}
```

?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @mishik this DO provide a correct answer, check the accepted answer and compare with mine, also I wrote it earlier but have no luck